# How to run audio from a batch file in the background?

Tags: windows-7, batch

Can it be done without any 3rd party software and if not, what should I use?

Comment: What do you mean with "without any prompting windows"? If you refer to a command prompt window, then the answer is always going to be no, because a batchfile always will produce a command prompt window. But there are other script services that don't give you a prompt.

Comment: What I mean is that if you start media player, a window appers

Comment: So you want something that plays music in the background?

Comment: You have a better chance of doing that on Linux but windows will probably be 3rd party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a vbscript to play an audio file. Create a new textfile and name it something like play.vbs

Your play.vbs file will look like this:

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Play audio
oPlayer.URL = "C:\welcome.mp3"
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

' Release the audio file
oPlayer.close
```

Comment: this should work

Answer (score 4):

[NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is a command line utility that can do a lot of things.  You can use it to play audio files for a specified amount of time in milliseconds.

> nircmd mediaplay 100000 "C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, very simple solution

Comment: You can also use -1 for duration to play the actual length of the audio file. Although it will become asynchronous.